# What is this (odd) art deco font with irregular letterforms?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I made this text for a site like a year ago and I can't for the life of me remember what font this is.   I went through every font on Photoshop, checked my fonts, Identifont and What Font Is so now I appeal to the Stack community; what font is this?[image]

Comment: I don't know, but look through 'art deco' categories on font sites.

Comment: If you have a good quality high contrast image of the font, you can try http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ Alternatively, you can describe the font using it's features. I have had less success with this. http://www.identifont.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [Chi-Town](http://www.dafont.com/chi-town.font) to me.

[image]

Comment: Looks spot on! How did you find this?

Comment: A quick browse of a couple free font sites.

Comment: I really hope @tfantina comes back someday and marks this as correct. I was really proud of finding this one. :)